# What is the dimension of a subspace containing $(1,1,1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, independence

Say $S=\{{(x,y,z):x=y=z}\}$, then every vector in $s \in S$ can be represented as $\lambda \cdot (1,1,1)$ with $\lambda \in R$. Vector $(1,1,1)$ is trivially independent since it is not zero.
Also, $sp(\{(1,1,1)\})=S$.
This tells us that $(1,1,1)$ is a basis of $S$ and
$\dim (S)=1$. However, I can continue the decomposition: $$ s = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} +  
\begin{pmatrix}0\\\lambda\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$ These vectors are obviously independent and span $S$ as well. So $\dim (S) = 3$, but we just saw that $\dim (S) = 1$. What is the right answer ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \lambda\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ \lambda\end{pmatrix}$ are not in $S$ for nonzero $\lambda$.

Comment: Amazing, thank you ! In general that would be the right way to find a basis, right ? Decompose as much as possible as long the the vectors belong to the set.

Comment: @Kreol Sure. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732467/how-do-i-find-a-basis-for-the-subspace-of-mathbbr4-spanned-by-the-four-vec) for an example given some vectors. In your example, if we allow say, $\pmatrix{1 \\0\\ 0},\pmatrix{0 \\ 1\\ 0},\pmatrix{0 \\ 0\\ 1}$ to be in $S$, then $S$ would no longer be closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. In general you can find some set of vectors that are in $S$ that span $S$, then check if they are linearly independent by reducing the matrix with rows as said vectors.